# incrementing a register n times skips values

Tags: regex, vim, vim-macros

I've been playing with 500 individual files using VIM to make one of the values unique. I won't paste that as it's a total kludge :)

After making one element Unique I have a single file with 500 records separated by a blank line.

Recorded a macro to mark row 1 then find the blank and mark the previous line then write that block to a file with @b incremented by 1.

Because I couldn't work out how to increment @a during the writing of the file I paste it increment it then yank it back to @a .

```
   "ap0:let @a="""^MAywdd
```

This all worked fine except every 7 numbers the increment command skips three so instead of XML0001.xml to XML0500.XML I get XML001.xml to XML0763.xml or thereabouts.

Why does the  skip 3 numbers every 8th invocation?

I'm just curious as at the moment as long as the files names are unique it doesn't matter what they are numbered but I will eventually need to make the output names match what the value of @b should be.

EDIT
Wild guess that it has something to do with the 0 to 9 registers losing track?

Is there a way to increment @a in insert mode something like

```
    :'a,'b w XML"Increment @A".xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The increment mystery

As your numbers are prefixed with `0`, Vim considers them to be **octal**, so the increment (with `<C-a>`, I suppose) jumps from `07` to `10`. To fix that, you can remove that (today rather obscure) number format:

```
:set nrformats-=octal
```

#### Directly increment register

If your register contained just the number, you could do:

```
:let @a = @a + 1
```

(Note: `+=` doesn't work, because the register is of string type.)

If your register contains the full filename, you have to use `:help sub-replace-expression` to match the first number and increment it:

```
:let @a = substitute(@a, '\d\+', '\=submatch(0) + 1', '')
```

#### Plugin recommendation

My [EditSimilar plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2544) provides a command that searches for a non-existing offset, and writes (portions of the buffer) to it:

```
:file XML0000.xml   " Name the original buffer
:9999WritePlus      " Writes XML0001.xml, XML0002.xml, etc.
```